# Unity RayCast does hit the object but it is NOT showing in the scene view or game view

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I recently started Unity and I ran into a problem with RayCasting. My code seems to work since the console gives me the information that the cube has been hit, but it doesn't show me the ray in the scene view nor the game view. The script I used is the following:

```cs
public class RayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    public LayerMask layersToHit;

    void Start()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f, Color.blue);

        CheckForColliders();
    }

    void CheckForColliders()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name + " was hit ");
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.red, 10f);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I also selected the LayersToHit in Unity to hit the connectors which are attached to the little cubes. What is wrong with the code for actually drawing the rays on the screen? Or do I need to change anything in the settings?
Thanks in advance!

edit: New code:

```cs
public class RayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Ray ray;
    public LayerMask layersToHit;

    void Start()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f, Color.blue);
        CheckForColliders();
    }

    void CheckForColliders()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name + " was hit ");
            //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.red, 10f);

        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You only run this on your start method so you won't be able to see it since it will only run once. Put it in your update method and you will be able to see it.

Comment: The 4th parameter of [DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) is duration. So it should in fact be drawnfor 10 seconds.
But you are not using your LayerMask in your actual Raycast. 
So are yo sure you are casting from the correct object and hitting the correct object? 
You should use the debugger to make sure our log ray.origin and ray.direction are are what you think they are.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK Alright I changed the start function into the update function and now when I run the game and then pause it, it indeed shows the ray. But when I haven't started it it still doesn't show anything. Is there a way to fix that? And while running the game it also doesn't show, only when pausing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works fine in my computer. So I think the problem might be a setting.
**Explanation:**

```
void Start()
{
    ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);

    /* Here you are drawing the first ray, you did not have a duration set
    for this one */
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f, Color.blue, 10f);

    CheckForColliders();
}

void CheckForColliders()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name + " was hit ");

        // Here you are drawing the line again.
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.red, 10f);
    }
}
```

This code runs fine but I´m not sure if you intended to draw the line twice, I presume the problem is the one I describe below, in the following link there is an image that shows the setting you may not have enabled and also shows the line being drawn.

[Check if the draw Gizmos button on the top right of the scene view window is enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDHdv.png)

Also if you want to be able to see the Ray without running the game your code should look like this:

```
private Ray ray;
public LayerMask layersToHit;


void Start()
{
    ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f, Color.blue);
    CheckForColliders();
}

void CheckForColliders()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name + " was hit ");
        //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.red, 10f);

    }
}
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.foward);
    Gizmos.color= Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f);
}
```

Comment: Hey, there has to be something else wrong with my settings or maybe installed products? When I copy your code it still doesn't show me any rays while the game is not running

Comment: Using the function OnDrawGizmos() shows the ray even if the game isn't running.

Comment: Is it not working with the part I just edited?

Comment: Alright I see the ray now while the game is running but I still don't see it when the game is NOT running. Yeah I used your part but it still doesn't show

Comment: Can you send me how your script looks now?

Comment: Yess I added the new code to my question

Comment: My bad just updated the answer, the ray wast drawing bcs while in the editor the ray wasn't being defined the new code should work now.

Comment: Hey, If you have time, would you want to help me with some more questions about Raycast?

Comment: Sure! DM me at https://twitter.com/michael_0427

Comment: Alright! I added you, since I can not sent a dm to you